# How to get current row value in a WITH MEMBER calculation MDX?

Tags: mdx, olap, business-intelligence, olap-cube, mondrian

I would like to calculate a Measure based on the current row.
Problem is I can't find a way to get the current row in a WITH MEMBER part.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS AVG(
    NonEmptyCrossJoin(
                FILTER(DESCENDANTS([Exigences].[ENVGR], [Levier], SELF),
                       [Exigences].CurrentMember.Name = 'Chemicals'),
                DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Valeo].[Powertrain Systems], [entity], SELF)),
    [Measures].[ProgressLevel])

SELECT {[Measures].[ProgressLevel], [Measures].[Test]} ON COLUMNS,
DESCENDANTS([Exigences].[ENVGR].[ENVGR-01.001], [Levier], SELF) ON
ROWS FROM [Exigences]
```

Chemicals is currently hard coded. That is for the example.
I would like in place of 'Chemicals' to have the current rows value.

So let's say those are the values rows will return 'Chemicals', 'Pharmacy', 'Test', I would like the [Measures].[Test] calculation to change.

Can MDX do that ? If so how can I get the current value.

I tried [Levier].CurrentMember.Name but I think it's conflicting with the [Exigences].CurrentMember.Name.

Any one has an idea ?

Thank you,

Comment: Not sure to understand, what do you mean by current row. Row of an underlying table ? if yes, which one ? (it's not very OLAP to get rowid :-) )

Comment: On the ON ROWS selection, I am doing a DESCENDANTS that will return me a set of [Levier] members. Now on the WITH MEMBER on top you can see hardcoded the 'Chemicals' string. I would like this string to be my [Levier].CurrentMember.Name value. But because of Filtering yet on the [Exigences] dimension I have a conflict, the equality test between [Exigences].CurrentMember.Name and [Levier].CurrentMember.Name will always be true, thus, filter won't filter anything.

Comment: I see your problem, tricky one. icCube OLAP server has a support for functional language which would solve the problem. Sorry, i don't see how to solve your problem unless doing something around Axis() or using a duplicated hierarchy. You need to create a variable, uff for this standard MDX su..s.

Comment: @icCube You are the first one to see it :) I am asking the whole web, but nobody can answer so far. I tried duplicating the hierarchy but it did not work as expected, I might have done it the wrong way I ll try again. What about Axis() ? What are yours suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This has been taking a bit of effort but that's the advantage to have a nice gold badge. We're using the [MDX Generate](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Generate.html) function and named sets (myCellSet & 2d example in [link](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Generate.html)) :

Not sure this is going to work for your provider but you can try this one :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS AVG(
 NonEmptyCrossJoin(
            Generate( {[Exigences].CurrentMember} as MyCellSet,
              FILTER(DESCENDANTS([Exigences].[ENVGR], [Levier], SELF),
                   [Exigences].CurrentMember.Name = MyCellSet.CurrentMember.Name)
            )
            ,
            DESCENDANTS([Organization].[Valeo].[Powertrain Systems], [entity], SELF)),
 [Measures].[ProgressLevel])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand why Generate do and why we do use it here but is the AS MyCellSet a standard way of using Generate. I can't find doc anywhere about it. And it seems that this is whats not working when trying to implement this. Off-topic : What do you mean by "to have a nice gold badge" ?

Comment: 928 point means you've been helping others, so it's fair we do the same

Comment: ahha Thanks. I just managed to do it by duplicating the Dimension. I dont like this solution but it will earn me some free time to find a better one. I'll try to digg some more on the Generate function. Thanks guys at icCube for providing some help. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's working on Microsoft-AS which is the 'de-facto' standard, after other vendors may follow or not. Sorry, can't find a link right now on this..

Comment: It's like a foreach: Generate( set, something ) -> for each member of the set do something and add the result of it (member,tuple,set) to the resulting set.